# slack bot scope missing while making api request

Tags: slack-api, slack, scopes

I have made a slack app in which I have a bot. I have selected channels:history, channels:read, channels:write under my permission scope, and also I have passed scopes

`"scope":"bot channel:history channel:read channel:write"`

while doing my oauth2 verification (using python), and I got a response where the scope is

```
"scope":"identify,bot,channels:history,channels:read,channels:write"
```

along with client and bot access tokens.

Now when I do an api call to fetch history of a channel in which my bot is invited to, I get

```
{ 
  ok: false,
  error: 'missing_scope',
  needed: 'channels:history',
  provided: 'identify,bot:basic' 
}
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong. How can I **PROVIDE** the channels:history scope in my api call. This is really driving me nuts. Should I be using the client access token, ie xoxp-xxxx, instead of bot token, ie xoxb-xxxx ?'

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For people having this problem in the future;

your integrated bot has full access to the slack api, whereas a bot in a slack app don't, as it will used publicly. When you successfully finish oauth2, you should get 2 tokens, `user access token` and `bot token`. The `user token` is used to read history from any channel/groups, and the `bot access token` is used to write to them. This means you constantly have to be switching from `user token` to `bot access token` in your app.

[image]

Also, remember that bot-user MUST be a member of a private channel which you want him to connect to.

Hope that helps.

Ps, if any found a better way going about this, feel free to answer below.

Comment: This helped me pass this specific error but got right after it a `not_in_channel`. I could bypass it by adding `chat:write.public` to the bot's scope (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402410/slack-slash-command-is-not-working-in-public-channels-unless-manually-added-to-t)

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not mention it: You also need to specify all required scopes on the admin page for your Slack app under "Oauth & Permission Scopes".

Comment: Yes in my Oauth and permission, i have bot and channels:history, channels:read and channels:write permissions as well. @erikkalkoken i will just edit my question to add this